# I want to retrieve data from two tables in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, join

I am working with MVC4 and datbase is in SQL server2008. I am not able to make joint between two tables. I want to retrieve data from two tables

Comment: Please share your current code.

Comment: You could look at creating a viewModel that you can access both tables